# Saltos de línea en formato DOS en Python

Tags: python, linux, windows

Tengo un script que guarda datos en un archivo de texto plano, pero corre sobre Linux. Cuando paso el archivo de texto a una máquina con Windows no me reconoce los saltos de línea y tengo que usar unix2dos para que lo haga.
Hay alguna manera de que los saltos de línea en formato DOS se hagan directo en el script sin tener que utilizar unix2dos ??

Saludos :)

Comment: Python no distingue qué fin de línea tiene el fichero. Es tu script quien los escribe, así que poco te podemos decir si no muestras el código que usas.

Comment: Hola Luis , bienvenido a SOes,  puedes poner el código de tu script y además explicar mejor lo que deseas obtener con ese script. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que tu script es el que genera el fichero y que el fichero lo ves bien en linux pero mal en windows.

Si esto es así se debe a que windows usa como fin de línea los caracteres \r\n (retorno de carro y nueva línea respectivamente) mientras que linux solo usa el \n. Como lo generas desde linux a windows le falta algo: el carácter 13 de la tabla ASCII conocido como Carriage Return e interpretado por compiladores usualmente como \r para que el programador lo pueda escribir.

Habría que cambiar algo así:

```
printf("Esto es una linea\nEsto es otra línea\n");
```

por:

```
printf("Esto es una linea\r\nEsto es otra línea\r\n");
```